# GPSD delivering wrong time

Tags: c++, gpsd

I'm currently having some fun with the `gspd` library and noticed that the time I get switches between two values - The actual value (today) and some date in 1991.

When displayed `gpsmon` it normally shows the right time. Using `cgps -s` displays the wrong time, with the absurdly huge offset.

The (so far) only possible problem I've found online is that the sys-time isn't up to date which mixes up the gps-time, but that isn't the case here.

We are accessing `gpsd` via the following code:

```
{
gps_stream(&gps_data, WATCH_ENABLE | WATCH_JSON, NULL);

    if(gps_waiting(&gps_data, timeout)) {
        if(gps_read(&gps_data) == -1) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

All the other values (location, altitude etc) are correct. Only the time is off.

Anybody got an idea on why this could be happening? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We actually found the answer! The RaspberryPi we ran this is on apparently had some issues with it's OS, so a using an old image worked out perfectly.